# loading angular modules after angular is initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, amd

I use **requirejs** for loading **angular** and angular's modules.

I want to require all necessary modules (e.g. angular-sanitize.js) together.

In my *require.config* I define following rule:

```
require.config({
    path: {
         'angular':'libs/angular-modules'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': { 
            deps: ['libs/angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

And in *libs/angular-modules.js* I define following module:

```
define(
    [
        'libs/angular-sanitize',
        'libs/angular-animate'
    ], 
    function () {
        return angular;
    }
);
```

I expect that at the time of loading modules *angular.js* will already be loaded. But sometimes I get error:

`Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined     angular-sanitize.js:8`

This is the eighth line of the *angular-sanitize.js*:

```
var $sanitizeMinErr = angular.$$minErr('$sanitize');
```

So it means that the *angular.js* file was not loaded but in network tab i see that it was.
I guess that at the time of initializing *angular-sanitize* module *angular.js* was loaded but was not initialized (`window.angular` has not yet been defined).

How I can determine that angular has been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to see a shim for `angular-sanitize` in your RequireJS configuration:

```
shim: {
    ... [whatever you already have] ,

    'angular-sanitize': { 
        deps: ['angular'],
    },
}
```

I have not put an `exports` option because I'm unsure what would make sense there. For AngularJS modules I would not expect anything to be *required* for `exports`.

The general rule of thumb is if you open the library's source and cannot find that it calls `define` by itself, then it needs a shim. `angular-animate` probably also needs a shim.

Comment: it's strange, but your example seems working. But I can't understand why. In my code I also specify dependency (`deps: ['libs/angular']`) for _angular-modules.js_ file (file which loads _angular-sanitize_ module).

Comment: If the error does not appear I mark your answer as "correct".

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load your dependencies in the route configuration resolve. Return a promise, and use Require to first load those dependencies, then resolve the promise:

```js
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: appConfig.getUrl('login'),
    resolve: { load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$log', function ($q, $rootScope, $log) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      require(appConfig.getDeps('login'), function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          forms.hideError();
          deferred.resolve();
        });
      });
      return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

AngularJs does not support lazy loading ... yet.

There are a few things floating around the internet that supposedly allow lazy loading, but in my opinion they are messy and overly bloated for minimal benefit

requireJS will not work with angular for this reason

Comment: So I guess I'm hallucinating when my application which uses RequireJS to load AngularJS on demand is **running perfectly**, right?

Comment: So @Louisll maybe you know how to prevent this error?

Comment: you're using requireJS to load dependencies of an angular project? or to load new controllers, etc to the existing module?

Comment: @DrogoNevets I use requireJs to load angular modules, controllers, directives and filters (all files of project).